# What is the English for 'трудовой десант'?

Tags: лексикон

I'm doing subtitles for the Soviet cult film, "Чучело", 1983, directed by Rolan Bykov:

- http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE_(%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC)
- http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085335/

One of the key words in the film is the Soviet ideological term, "трудовой десант". That means, when, say, a whole school volunteers to work somewhere, for example, at a collective farm for some time, and they earn money for that. My question is: how can I translate the term "трудовой десант" in a way that English-speaking people could understand that? 
My own variants are two:
 1. literary translation, 'labour landing' - I leave it in quotation marks and let the audience guess what it is by what they see next in the film; and
 2. 'volunteer job' - that's the variant which explains the idea of what they do, but 'volunteering' typically means no payment, that's why I don't like it...

Please, share your ideas on the way this Soviet term can be translated, because it's crucial for the understanding of the film, I'd like the people who watch it get the meaning of it at once.

Comment: Consider http://english.stackexchange.com/ or voting for this SE http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners

Comment: I haven't asked to translate it, I just asked to share ideas on which of my own translations is better, to appreciate them.

Comment: You question says "What is the English for ...", isn't it a request for translation?

Comment: Still I gave 2 translations of my own and asked to choose between them... Anyhow, you know it better.

Comment: I want to make it clearer, why the post was closed. You say that you understand the meaning of the expression, but you don't know the English equivalent. Thus, it is a question about the English vocabulary, not the Russian one. We cannot help you, but English Language and Usage probably can.

Comment: ELU mod here. This is a tough call. If you describe the phrase you are looking for in English — and you already do, but an additional sentence or two would be nice —, and then ask for a shorter/idiomatic way to say that, that's a [phrase-request], on-topic on ELU. *After* you do that, you can still mention the exact equivalent in another language, but the key is that the question must still work with that bit removed. Do note that some people might instinctively click on "close" as soon as they see Cyrillic in the title. So make sure to work around that as well. Thank you.

Comment: @YellowSky If you manage to fix your question according to RegDwight's suggestions, flag your question, choose "other" and write "migrate to English". I'll migrate your question there for you. :)

Comment: Actually, *трудовой десант* is more of a labour duty than volunteering (on the part of the schoolchildren at least).

Comment: Actually if the equivalent exists, you should look for int in American/English World War II lexicon. Historically during the early years of Soviet Union many aspects of life the was thought 'in military' context. So, many military terms were used to describe labor - трудовой фронт, герой труда, ударный труд (ср. "ударная армия"), трудовой десант, "трудовые резервы", etc. All these expressions lived until last days of SU, but in 70's most of them has lost their initial 'heroic' feeling, but were used as cliché.

Comment: I suggest "labour drop force".